# How to deal with these unknown/weird variable types?

Tags: python, abaqus

Abaqus FEM software, which uses Python, creates its own variable/list types, for example:

```
a = mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['Instance-1'].faces
print a
type(a)
```

> ['Face object', 'Face object', 'Face object', ...]
>
> type 'FaceArray'

```
print a[0]:
type(a[0])
```

> ({'featureName': 'Name-1', 'index': 6, 'instanceName': 'Name-1',
>   'isReferenceRep': False, 'pointOn': ((0.0, 0.733333, -0.133333),)})
>
> type 'Face'

When I now initialize `x=[]` and add a *'Face object'* with `x.append(a[2])`, it results in

> [mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.instances['Instance-1'].faces[2]]

instead of

> ['Face object']

How can I create a new variable of the same format as *a*?

Comment: What does `type(x[0])` return?

Comment: It returns:
> type 'NoneType'

Answer (score 0):

u have to create face array not simple array, then add into your face array Face objects

```
x = FaceArray()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work and returns:
> NameError: name 'FaceArray' is not defined

Comment: http://ivt-abaqusdoc.ivt.ntnu.no:2080/v6.14/books/ker/default.htm?startat=pt01ch07pyo05.html

getByBoundingBox function returns face array, that means it contains the constructor of face array

Comment: Thanks for your help. What does that mean to me exactly? Like how can I make use of the fact, that getByBoundingBox contains the constructor information in this case?

Comment: somewhere in function getByBoundingBox calls the method which creates facearray (because the return variable type is facearray), your only task is to find it, and from that point u can create your own facearray (personally i never used abaqus, but it contains surely .py files)

Comment: A couple of functions return a facearray, but that does not help a lot. The constructor is seemlingly not available.